# How can I use several media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this code and I have tried to figure out why it's not working. I have read several answers to quite similar questions, but I just don't get any wiser. Is the code in let us say (max-width:480) applying to all the other larger media queries? The only thing I can see working is the (max-width:1000)

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .figur {
    display: none;
  }
  #about {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #map {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .parallax {
    background-image: url("../img/bamseLiten.jpeg");
  }
  .row .column {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }  
}
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
  #logo {
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    align-self: center;
  }
  .menu li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Please use any code sharing site like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or any other to better demonstrate your problem

Comment: Is `.figur` a typo? You can remove the MQ (first line with condition and `{`+`}`) and see if rules in it now have an effect (maybe the image is a 404). I use the following debug display: https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/VrRagy (with a lot of background-color on elements and body), it may be useful to you too :)

Answer (score 0):

How are you testing this?

You need to make sure you are able to change the screen size... chrome offers decent ability to do this with inspect.

You may want to try using a min-width along with the max?

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 990px) {
  .class {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     height:40px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm inspecting with web-developer(by Pederick)-resize-view responsive layouts. Only one of the seven things I want to change actually changes. So I'm thinking it must be something I have misunderstood. Do I need to repeat the conditions in smaller media queries or do they add together when the screen size is smaller than 480 pixels?

Comment: Are you asking if media queries stack? If so, then yes! They stack like the usual css ... If there is a conflict then the last declared media query takes over. It's the same cascading effect.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum device comparability and adopting you can use bootstrap 4+ like *Media Query*

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (max-width: 575px) { 
}

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (max-width: 767px) { 

}

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (max-width: 991px) { 

}

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
 @media (max-width: 1199px) { 

 }
```

For ultra mobile first you can use `min-width` instead of `max-width` which is like this -

```
// Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
@media (min-width: 576px) { 

}

// Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
@media (min-width: 768px) { 

}

// Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
}

// Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
 @media (min-width: 1200px) { 

 }
```

Hope you will get a better responsive layout using one of this media query.. Thanks

Comment: Also you can grab two breakpoints from `min-width` to `max-width` for targeting single elements which is like this `@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767px) { ... }`